# Proper way of passing a parameter to a linq query in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm

I've been struggling to find a way to calculate the total number of days in a selected month without the weekends. (MDate is binded to my datepicker)

As an absolute beginner I lack the understanding to pass my data parameter (mDate) to the linq query but here's how far I've gotten:

```
public class LocationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

public LocationiewModel()
{
    SetDaysInMonth();
}

private DateTime mDate = DateTime.Now;

public DateTime MDate
{
    get { return mDate; }
    set
    {
        if (value == mDate)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            mDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MDate");

            SetDaysInMonth();
        }

    }

}

int _daysInMonth;

public int DaysInMonth
{
    get { return _daysInMonth; }
    set
    {
        _daysInMonth = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("DaysInMonth");
    }
}

private void SetDaysInMonth(DateTime mDate)

{
    int DaysInMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(mDate.Year, mDate.Month))
                                 .Select(day => new DateTime(mDate.Year, mDate.Month, day))
                                 .Count(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && 
                                             d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday);
}
```

It makes sense to me but I am clearly lacking something because I get the following error: `Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'mDate' of 'LocationViewModel.SetDaysInMonth(DateTime)'`.

Can someone please show me what I am missing to get this to work? After hours of reading, I would be really grateful to eventually understand what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: `SetDaysInMonth(value);` (too short for an answer)

Comment: Gert, I've tried it but I couldn't get it to work. The error went away but the result is 0. What am I doing wrong. Does "value" have to be in all the SetDaysInMonth methods? If you could answer by changing my code and it works I would accept your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested your linq by doing the following

```
Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(2017, 10))
                            .Select(day => new DateTime(2017, 10, day))
                            .Count(day => day.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && day.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

The result was 22 which is correct.

I would recommend simplifying your setter to the following

```
    private DateTime mDate = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime MDate
    {
        get { return mDate; }
        set
        {
                mDate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MDate");

                SetDaysInMonth();
        }
}
```

This might fix the problem because you have not have been falling into this block of code.

Also verify that the output window is not throwing any binding errors and that you have your binding mode set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your linq; but your parameter passing and reference to property is incorrect. If your linq is good, following changes will fix the issue.

No need to pass parameter, you can use the MDate property directly. Similarly you can set the DaysInMonth directy.

```
private void SetDaysInMonth()

{
    this.DaysInMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(this.MDate.Year, this.MDate.Month))
                                 .Select(day => new DateTime(this.MDate.Year, this.MDate.Month, day))
                                 .Count(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && 
                                             d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, loopedcode, we are half way there! I've got rid of the error and I was hoping it would work but the result of my query is 0 when I bind it to a textbox. What am I missing in the query?